# Raspberry Pi B+ Stuck at 2 volts output

Tags: gpio

I recently set up a remote controlled car with the raspberry pi using the L293D motor controller chip and I was using pins 32 and 33 (Board Numbering) everything was working perfectly until pin 33 started being stuck on 2 volts output. I could still control it by setting it low but as soon as the command stopped it went high again? Any thoughts on what could have changed in a day?

Comment: How are you measuring the voltage?  Is anything connected when you do so?  Do any parts get hot?  Ultimately you need to figure out if this is physical damage from electrical abuse, conflicting software on the pi, or the influence of the load circuit overpowering the GPIO.

Comment: I am measuring voltage with a DC 10 volt multimeter and I have my motor controller circuit setup but the battery to it is turned off. Also I have GPIO pin 32 setup and it is acting fine?